# It is possible to auto create folder if VistaFolderBrowserDialog selected not exists?

Tags: c#, .net

I using [Ookii.Dialog](http://www.ookii.org/software/dialogs).

When I use VistaFolderBrowserDialog to selected a folder, I hope if the selected folder not exists it will ask for create it instead alert the folder not exists.

How can I do some thing like that? is there any events or options?

This is my code.

```
VistaFolderBrowserDialog dialog = new VistaFolderBrowserDialog();
dialog.Description = "Select Export Folder:";
dialog.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
dialog.SelectedPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(lastSelectPath), 
       Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(lastAppendFilepath));
```

Comment: `VistaFolderBrowserDialog` is not part of the .NET framework. I think I know which library you are using but it would be better if you [edited your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18856281/edit) and explicitly said which library you got it from (or if you wrote it your self)

Comment: Sorry about that, I am using the Ookii.Dialog

Comment: Are you wanting it to create the folder before the dialog is shown and make the `SelectedPath` set to that newly created folder, or are you wanting if they choose a folder that does not exist it will create the folder after they press OK in the dialog?

Comment: After user click the Select button. The control only allow select exists folder, so, I can not deal with the not exists folder.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is check if the directory exists with [`Directory.Exists(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists.aspx), ask the user via a [`MessageBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x49kd7z.aspx), then create the directory with [`Directory.CreateDirectory(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s.aspx).

```
var initialDirectory = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(lastSelectPath), 
       Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(lastAppendFilepath));

if(!Directory.Exists(initalDirectory))
{
    if(MessageBox.Show("Folder does not exist", "The default folder does not exist, create it?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
        Directory.CreateDirectory(initalDirectory);
}

VistaFolderBrowserDialog dialog = new VistaFolderBrowserDialog();
dialog.Description = "Select Export Folder:";
dialog.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
dialog.SelectedPath = initalDirectory;
```

Note that there are reasons `Directory.CreateDirectory(initalDirectory)` could thrown an exception. For example, you try to create a directory where you do not have permissions to create directories. You may want to wrap the two lines in a try-catch block and handle any errors appropriately.

Comment: But I want to this happened when user click the Select button. If I create if before select, will produce too much useless folder.

Comment: Maybe this is the only alternative choose. I want it ask for create folder after user selected or input a not exists folder.

Comment: Then use a `if` `else` statements, I don't understand what the problem with this is.